# Overconstrained linear system. Minimizing error for "quasi-solutions".

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

This is a practice-motivated problem, and I know very little about optimization, so I come here for help.

> Consider the system
>
> $$A\mathbf x=\mathbf b$$
>   Where $\mathbf x, \,\mathbf b$ are $n$ dimensional, and $A$ is $m\times n, \,(m>n)$.

This system, is overconstrained, and it's very common for it to have no solutions.

However, suppose I have the system
\begin{align}
2x+2y&=2\\
1x+1y&=0.95\\
1x+0y&=1
\end{align}

Now, the first and second equations are "almost" linearly dependent. So what I want to do is add an "error correcting" vector $\varepsilon$ such that the system has solution, i.e
$$
A\mathbf x=\mathbf b \mapsto A\mathbf x=\mathbf b+\varepsilon \tag 1
$$

Where the system with $\varepsilon$ has solution(s). Now, in most cases, we'll lots of choices for the error correction.

What I want to do, is to minimize it, such that the solutions will be the 'best possible'.

So, after all, I believe I'd want to minimize $\|\varepsilon\|$ subject to "$ A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf b+\varepsilon$ has solutions".

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Just apply Lagrangian multiplier.

Answer (score 1):

Interpret $A$ as a linear transformation $A:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$.
The equation$Ax=b$ can be solved if and only if $b\in\text{Im}(A)$, which is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$.

With this framework, it's easy to see that $\epsilon=P_Ab-b$, where $P_A:\mathbb{R}^m\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\text{Im}(A)$.